# How do I plot a bubble chart with two different size aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below creates some sample data -

```
  library(tidyverse)
  library(ggrepel)
  
  location = c("Houston", "Orlando", "Baltimore", "Twin Cities", "Fairfax", "Restion")
  cys = c(34000, 67000, 78000, 67000, 45000, 78000)
  ebi = c(60000, 34000, 56000, 78000, 34000, 90000)
  ability = c(.50, .78, .67, .56, .79, .65)
  potential = c(.70, .89, .78, .67, .80, .70)
  segment = c("Constant Growth", "Generally Up", "Generally Down", "Slow Decline", "Constant Decline",
              "Constant Growth")

  data = tibble(location, cys, ebi, ability, potential, segment)  
  
  data
```

I would like to make a plot with -

- ability on the x axis
- potential on the y axis
- cys as the bubble size
- ebi as the ring size
- segment as the bubble fill (constant growth = dark green, generally up = light green, generally down = grey, slow decline = light red, constant decline = dark red.

See attached picture to understand what I mean by ring size and bubble size

[image]

I have used the following code to plot the x and y axis with cys as the bubble size -

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ability, potential))+
  geom_point(aes(label = cys, size = cys))+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = location))
```

However I am unsure how to add the ring size (ebi) on top of cys. Can anyone help me with this. I feel like I have so somehow set the ebi fill as white and color as blue, then somehow add cys on top on that.

Note - if cys exceeds ebi (like Orlando), I would like to still be able to see the ebi ring with the cys bubble overlapping. See screenshot below as an example-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two separate layer for dot and ring. I am using

- `see::geom_point2` because it doesn't have this "weird margin"
- `ggnewscale` to create a new legend for the second size scale
- converting segment to a factor, in order to use it with a Brewer palette for the "bubble color" because I prefer use of well conceived palettes rather than trying to reinvent the wheel and find colors that in the end may still not be discernible by 5-10% of people (color blindness). Check https://colorbrewer2.org/

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(see)
library(ggnewscale)

cys <- c(34000, 67000, 78000, 67000, 45000, 78000)
ebi <- c(60000, 34000, 56000, 78000, 34000, 90000)
ability <- c(.50, .78, .67, .56, .79, .65)
potential <- c(.70, .89, .78, .67, .80, .70)
segment <- factor(gsub(" ", "_", tolower(c(
  "Constant Growth", "Generally Up", "Generally Down", "Slow Decline", "Constant Decline",
  "Constant Growth"
))), levels = rev(c(
  "constant_growth",
  "generally_up",
  "generally_down",
  "slow_decline",
  "constant_decline"
)))

data <- tibble(cys, ebi, ability, potential, segment)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(ability, potential)) +
  geom_point2(aes(size = cys, color = segment), alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn" ) +
  new_scale(new_aes = "size") +
  geom_point(aes(size = ebi), shape = 1)
```

[image]

<sub>One small word to your visualisation - it might be very confusing for the reader, you are trying to visualise 5 dimensions here, of which two are coded as circle sizes - not easy to differentiate those... maybe reconsider your visualisation, e.g. use of facets?</sub>

```r
# I'd prefer the figure without colors, but with facets instead: 

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(ability, potential)) +
  geom_point2(aes(size = cys), alpha = 0.6) +
  new_scale(new_aes = "size") +
  geom_point(aes(size = ebi), shape = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ segment)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

(I have removed the labels because they are not very relevant for the question. You can also just add colors / fill in the normal way).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the suggestions. This really helps.